# Single chip with multiple options in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-chips

I'm trying to create a chip similar to the google play books one.

[image]

With a similar behavior to this:

[image]

Do I need to create a custom class extending Chip or ChipDrawable?

Comment: Does the Chip have one single action or multiple one?

Comment: Multiple actions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to create your custom `View` that extend behavior from `Chip` if you want it to work in `Chip Group`.
Also you can check [Toggle Button](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button) it look like you can use `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` with `Flow` from `constraintLayout`.